# Android Webview FindNext Skipping highlighted words

Tags: android, text, webview, find

I'm using a button to find text in a webview. It is working ok, and the results are correctly highlighted.

However, I have another button to do the function "Find Next". It works, but only scrolls webview to odd results (1, 3, 5, 7 , 9...), skipping the pair results (2, 4, 6 , 8 ...).

The results are all highlighted (1, 2, 3, 4, 5...), but the FindNext function skips the odd results.

The code i'm using for "find next" function is this:

```
    public void pesq_proxima (View view) {

    WebView webview1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    EditText edittext1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    webview1.findAllAsync(edittext1.getText().toString());
    try {
        webview1.findNext(true);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

Does anybody can help me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check that edittext1.getText().toString() is change or not if changed do webview1.findAllAsync(edittext1.getText().toString());
else webview1.findNext(true); is enough

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to run **findNext()** after the first async match of **findAllAsync()**, hence you could use WebView.FindListener like this.

```
webview.setFindListener(new FindListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFindResultReceived(int activeMatchOrdinal, int numberOfMatches, boolean isDoneCounting) {
        webView.findNext(true);
    }
});
```